# Controlled input in form throwing error upon submission

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, apollo-client

I have been trying to submit a login request using a form with controlled input. A `submit` function is passed down the React components to be triggered upon `onClick` of a material-ui `Button`. This error is only thrown when I send a mutation request using Apollo Client.

```
index.js:1375 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

From my understanding of [controlled components in React's docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), `input` components are "controlled" by using React `value` and `setValue` state hooks in `value` and `onChange` attributes.

This is the top level `Login` component that contains the `submit` function and `useMutation` hook. `submit` is first passed down to a `LoginForm` component.

```
const Login = () => {
  const [login, { data }] = useMutation(LOGIN);
  console.log(data);

  const submit = async form => {
    console.log(form); // form object looks correct
    await login({ variables: form });
  };

...

    <Container>
      <LoginForm submit={submit} />
    </Container>
```

This is the `LoginForm` component, which renders a `GeneralForm` component. Again, `submit` is passed down to `GeneralForm`.

```
const fields = [
  {
    id: "username",
    label: "Username",
    required: true,
    placeholder: "example: 98sean98"
  },

...

const LoginForm = props => {
  const { submit } = props;

...

    <Container>
      <GeneralForm fields={fields} submit={submit} />
    </Container>
```

This is the `GeneralForm` component.

```
const GeneralForm = props => {
  const { fields, submit } = props;
  const [form, setForm] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fields.forEach(field => {
      form[field.id] = "";
    });
    setForm(form);
  }, [form, fields]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    form[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
    setForm(setForm);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (validateForm(form)) { // returns a boolean indicating validity
      submit(form); // trigger the submit function that is passed down from <Login />
    } else {
      alert("invalid form");
    }
  };

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      {fields.map(field => (
        <FormControl key={field.id} required={field.required}>
          <InputLabel htmlFor={field.id}>{field.label}</InputLabel>
          <Input
            required={field.required}
            id={field.id}
            type={field.type ? field.type : "text"}
            aria-describedby={
              field.helperText ? `${field.id}-helper-text` : null
            }
            placeholder={field.placeholder}
            value={form[field.id]}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          {field.helperText ? (
            <FormHelperText id={`${field.id}-helper-text`}>
              {field.helperText}
            </FormHelperText>
          ) : null}
        </FormControl>
      ))}

      <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </FormGroup>
  );
};
```

My dev environment

```
partial packages list:
  "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.7.0",
  "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
  "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
  "graphql": "^14.5.8",
  "react": "^16.10.2",
  "react-dom": "^16.10.2",

Machine: MacOS X Catalina 10.15.1
```

The **peculiar behaviour** I'm observing now is that without calling the Apollo Client mutation request,

```
const submit = async form => {
  console.log(form);
  // await login({ variables: form });
};
```

the above error does not get triggered. So, I wonder if Apollo Client is altering my `form` object incorrectly in some way.

Comment: Have u tried setting the initial value to ''(empty string) for the respective input value.

Comment: the warning appears if the vaöue switches form undefined to defined or vice versa. I assume that `form[field.id]` is undefined on render. Try `form[field.id] || ''` to remove the warning.

Comment: I just tried that, the input does not get updated at all `onChange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent some time digging around the internet, and this [resource](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-controlled-components) seems to be quite helpful. Apparently, all I had to do was to switch the `value` attribute of `Input` to listening to `value` that is exposed by React state in the same component instead of `form[field.id]` passed down from another component.

```
// GeneralForm.js
...
const [value, setValue] = useState(form[field.id] ? form[field.id] : "");
...
<Input value={value} ... />
```

So, I modularised the `Input` component along with its parent `FormControl` into another file called `FormInput.js`, and arrived at this solution.

```
// FormInput.js
const FormInput = props => {
  const { field, form, setForm } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(form[field.id] ? form[field.id] : "");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <FormControl key={field.id} required={field.required}>
      <InputLabel htmlFor={field.id}>{field.label}</InputLabel>
      <Input
        required={field.required}
        id={field.id}
        type={field.type ? field.type : "text"}
        aria-describedby={field.helperText ? `${field.id}-helper-text` : null}
        placeholder={field.placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {field.helperText ? (
        <FormHelperText id={`${field.id}-helper-text`}>
          {field.helperText}
        </FormHelperText>
      ) : null}
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

Then, I import `FormInput` into `GeneralForm`, passing down all necessary props.